# Get case class annotations with reflection?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have a case class like:

```
case class Foo (@Annotation bar: String)
```

I'd like to be able to get access to that annotation and any of its information that is stored

I can get the case accessors using scala reflection (using 2.11.8) with

```
val caseAccessors = 
  universe.typeTag[T].
    tpe.
    decls.
    filter(_.isMethod).
    map(_.asMethod).
    filter(_.isCaseAccessor)
```

But when I try and access `.annotations` on them there is nothing. I realize that the annotation is technically on the constructor parameter, but how do I get to it?

Comment: Does your annotation extend `scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation`?

Comment: No, these are java annotations in another library that have a runtime retention on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@Annotation` will be on both constructor parameter and companion object `apply` method, and you can find those by name. I don't think there exist specific methods to filter out constructor / primary constructor / companion object factory method. Both these should work:

```
universe.typeTag[Foo]
  .tpe
  .declarations
  .find(_.name.toString == "<init>")
  .get
  .asMethod
  .paramss
  .flatten
  .flatMap(_.annotations)

universe.typeTag[Foo.type]
  .tpe
  .declarations
  .find(_.name.toString == "apply")
  .get
  .asMethod
  .paramss
  .flatten
  .flatMap(_.annotations)
```

(although I'm on Scala 2.11.8 and there's no `decls` but there's `declarations`)

If you want to put your annotations on fields or getters, use `scala.annotation.meta` package:

```
import scala.annotation.meta
case class Foo (@(Annotation @meta.getter) bar: String)
```

In this case your code will work (if you change `T` to `Foo` in `typeTag[T]`)

See the doc for [`scala.annotation.meta`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html)

Comment: Nice and the only thing that worked for me... But how can I connect it with the member value of the case class?