# How to list annotations (custom java ones and others) on field members of Scala case class

Tags: scala, annotations

So I'm trying to list fields with specific annotation in a Scala case class and I'm not able to get it working... Let's see come code right away

The case class (it's a simplified version of it, mine extends another class and is also nested in my test class where I use it for unit testing only):

```
case class Foo(@Unique var str: String) {}
```

The custom Java annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Unique {}
```

And my class (simplified again) where I'm trying to do some stuffs with fields marked as unique

```
class SomeClass[T] (implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]) {
    val fields: Iterable[universe.TermSymbol] = typeOf(typeTag).members.collect { case s: TermSymbol => s }.
                                                filter(s => s.isVal || s.isVar)
    val list = fields.flatMap(f => f.annotations.find(_.tpe =:= TypeOf[Unique]).((f, _))).toList
}
```

But the val list in the last peace of code is always empty... `fields` has `str` listed in but without the annotation.

What am I missing?

The code listing the annotations is from the following answer:
[How to list all fields with a custom annotation using Scala's reflection at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792383/how-to-list-all-fields-with-a-custom-annotation-using-scalas-reflection-at-runt)

Comment: You are probably putting annotation on constructor params only. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176273/get-case-class-annotations-with-reflection/41197711) could be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the reference post is **Scala 2.10** is old and is not compatible with the newest Scala version.

There is an example for how to **get the specify annotation** by **type**.

```
  def listProperties[T: TypeTag]: List[universe.Annotation] = {
    typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
      .asClass
      .primaryConstructor
      .typeSignature
      .paramLists.flatten.flatMap(_.annotations)
  }

  val annotations = listProperties[Foo].filter(_.tree.tpe =:= typeOf[Unique])
  println(annotations)
```

and there is way to get the annotation's field value:

```
  case class Foo(@Unique(field = "bar") val str: String) {}
  import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  val result = tb.eval(tb.untypecheck(head.tree)).asInstanceOf[Unique]
```

and need to call out your annotation class is implemented by using **Java** style, In **Scala** maybe you want to use `StaticAnnotation` for creating `Annotation`, like:

```
  class Unique extends StaticAnnotation
```